# PowerShell forwarding events from remote PS Session

Tags: powershell

Using the **Register-EnginerEvent -Forward**  and **New-Event** I am trying to forward object events from a remote server to the host server however it does not seem to work.

To prove the theory, tried the below simple code which **does** work:

```
$TargetServer = 'localhost'

Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier TimerEventOccured -Action {
   Write-Host "$(Get-Date -format "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") - $($event.MessageData) received..." -ForegroundColor Green
} | Out-Null

$TimerScriptBlock = {
    Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier TimerEventOccured -Forward | Out-Null
    $Count = 1
    while($Count -lt 3) {
        New-Event -SourceIdentifier TimerEventOccured -MessageData 'Timertriggered'
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
        $Count += 1
    }
}

$RemoteTimerScriptBlockJob = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $TargetServer -ScriptBlock $TimerScriptBlock -AsJob

while($RemoteTimerScriptBlockJob.State -in @('NotStarted','Running')) {
    Write-Host "$(Get-Date -format "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") - remote timer job still running"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}
Write-Host "$(Get-Date -format "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") - remote timer job complete"
```

...where as the below adding **Register-ObjectEvent**, which is what I want to achieve, **doesn't**.

```
$TargetServer = 'localhost'

Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier TimerEventOccured -Action {
   Write-Host "$(Get-Date -format "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") - $($event.MessageData) received..." -ForegroundColor Green
} | Out-Null

$TimerScriptBlock = {
    Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier TimerEventOccured -Forward | Out-Null
    $timer = New-Object timers.timer 
    $timer.Enabled = $true 
    $timer.Interval = 3000
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName elapsed –SourceIdentifier thetimer -Action $action {
        New-Event -SourceIdentifier TimerEventOccured -MessageData 'Timertriggered'
    }
    $timer.start()
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 15 #just wait long enough for timer events to trigger a few times
}

$RemoteTimerScriptBlockJob = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $TargetServer -ScriptBlock $TimerScriptBlock -AsJob

while($RemoteTimerScriptBlockJob.State -in @('NotStarted','Running')) {
    Write-Host "$(Get-Date -format "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") - remote timer job still running"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}
Write-Host "$(Get-Date -format "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") - remote timer job complete"
```

Could you please help? Thanks.

**Update:**

Please note, I could directly forward the timer-event to the source server without needing the engine-event as the intermediary. But above timer event was only used to illustrate the point here. The real work I am dealing with is to monitor Windows Event log for certain event ids (which has become quite complex to share here).

So, if I were to use -forward directly on the Eventlog listener Object then it will create a lot of traffic from target servers to host session (i.e. every event written  will be dispatched as opposed to the only ones I am after). I want to be able to process the triggered event first on the remote server itself (to match the input eventIDs) and then forward the filtered event through engine event, which is where I am stuck.

Comment: My first guess is double hop issue. You’re trying to remote twice without passing credentials or configuring delegation

Comment: No, -forward is a perfectly valid usage, as has been proven by the first example

Comment: @All - please note, I could directly forward the timer-event without needing the engine-event. But above timer event was only used to illustrate the point here. The real work i am dealing with is to monitor Windows Event log for certain event ids. If I were to use -forward directly then it will create a lot of traffic from target servers to host session. I want to be able to process the triggered event first (to match the input eventIDs) and the forward the filtered event through engine event

Comment: Note that there are two incidental problems with your code: A stray `$action` variable before the script-block literal passed to `-Action`, and the fact that you have _both_ `$timer.Enabled` and `$timer.Start()`, which do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: [`Register-ObjectEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent) isn't the problem in your case - it is the fact that you use a *single* `Start-Sleep` call after which you *exit immediately*, which causes most of the events to be lost.

---

When you suspend PowerShell's own foreground thread with [`Start-Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep), you also suspend its event processing.

Specifically, this plays out as follows in your case:

- While `Start-Sleep` runs, events are *queued* - the immediate side effect of which is that your events aren't processed in a timely fashion.
- When `Start-Sleep` ends and the foreground thread regains control, the event queue starts getting processed, but since the script block *ends right away*, only an - unpredictable - *subset* of the queued events gets processed before overall execution of the remote script block ends. Seemingly, PowerShell doesn't ensure that queued events are processed before exiting.

Thus, if you break you single `Start-Sleep -Seconds 15` call into multiple ones, giving PowerShell time to process events in between, your code should work:

```
1..3 | ForEach-Object { Start-Sleep -Seconds 5 }
```

Again, note that there's no guarantee that if events still happen to be queued afterwards that they will be processed before exiting.

**However** - as you've later discovered - you can **use [`Wait-Event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/wait-event) `-Timeout` as a superior alternative to `Start-Sleep`, because it does *not* block `-Action` script-block and `-Forward` event processing** while it waits, allowing for the forwarded events to be processed in near-realtime.

- Note: `Wait-Event`'s (and also [`Get-Event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-event)'s) primary purpose is to retrieve and output *queued* events, i.e. events that are *not* consumed by `Register-ObjectEvent` / `Register-EngineEvent` event subscriptions *based on `-Action` or `-Forward`* and must be retrieved and acted on *on demand*. However, as a beneficial side effect, `Wait-Event` also enables *registration-based (subscriber-based)* event processing (via `-Action` script blocks and `-Forward`) to occur while it waits.

The following self-contained example, which builds on your code:

- Shows the use of `Wait-Event`, both in the remote script block and locally.
- Retrieves the output produced directly by the remote script block, using [`Receive-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job)
- Performs cleanup, both of the remote job and the locale event subscription.
- For details, refer to the source-code comments.
- Note: Because "loopback remoting" is used, the local machine must be set up for remoting and you must run WITH ELEVATION (as admin) - the [`#Requires -RunAsAdministrator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Requires#-runasadministrator) directive enforces the latter.

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
# Running ELEVATED is a must if you use Invoke-Command -ComputerName with the local machine.

$TargetServer = 'localhost'

$eventJob = Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier TimerEventOccurred -Action {
   Write-Host "$(Get-Date -format "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") - $($event.MessageData) received #$((++$i))..." -ForegroundColor Green
}

$TimerScriptBlock = {
    $null = Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier TimerEventOccurred -Forward 
    $timer = New-Object timers.timer 
    $timer.Interval = 1000 # Fire every second
    $null = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName elapsed –SourceIdentifier thetimer -Action {
      Write-Host "$(Get-Date -format "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") - $($event.MessageData) TRIGGERED #$((++$i))..."
      New-Event -SourceIdentifier TimerEventOccurred -MessageData 'Timertriggered'
    }
    $timer.start()
    # Produce events for a certain number of seconds.
    $secs = 5
    # Wait-Event - unlike Start-Sleep - does NOT block the event processing.
    # Note that since events created in this remote session are either forwarded
    # or handled via an -Action script block, Wait-Event will produce *no output*.
    Wait-Event -Timeout $secs
    # Hack only to make this sample code work more predictably: 
    # Ensure that the last event gets processed too:
    # -Timeout only accepts *whole* seconds and unpredictable runtime conditions
    # can result in the last event to not have been processed yet when Wait-Event returns.
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100; Get-Event
    "Exiting remote script block after $secs seconds."
  }

$remoteTimerScriptBlockJob = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $TargetServer -ScriptBlock $TimerScriptBlock -AsJob


Write-Host "Processing events while waiting for the remote timer job to complete..."
do {
  # Note that since the TimerEventOccurred is handled via an -Action script block,
  # Wait-Event will produce *no output*, but it enables processing of those script blocks,
  # unlike Start-Sleep.
  Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier TimerEventOccurred -Timeout 3
} while ($remoteTimerScriptBlockJob.State -in 'NotStarted', 'Running')

Write-Host "$(Get-Date -format "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") - Remote timer job terminated with the following output:"
# Receive the remote script block's output and clean up the job.
$remoteTimerScriptBlockJob | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob

# Also clean up the local event job.
$eventJob | Remove-Job -Force # -Force is needed, because event jobs run indefinitely.
# Note: This automatically also removes the job as an event subscriber, so there's no need
#       for an additional Unregister-Event call.
```

Example output:

[image: sample output]

Comment: Thanks @Mklemento - I always thought start-sleep is applicable to the current thread and event hander processing ran in another thread.

Comment: Your suggestions are right. It's all working now. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Steve. Yeah, processing at least `-Action` script blocks (as opposed to calling `Get-Event` in the foreground thread) in a separate thread would make sense.

Comment: On second thought, @Steve: Using a separate thread would introduce thread-safety issues, which would be a challenge to deal with.